# Time to apply transaction logs: does it matter how many logs?

Tags: sql-server, transaction-log

When restoring from a backup in SQL Server, the procedure is to restore the `.bak` file and then apply any `.trn` files since the last full backup.

Does it make a difference how many `.trn` files there are, if they cover the same transactions? I.e. is it faster or slower restore a 1-hour `.trn` file vs twelve 5-minute `.trn` logs?

Comment: There would be a very small amount of overhead associated with reading the headers of the 12 files as opposed to 1 header.  The actual rollback/roll-forward work performed by SQL Server would be no different.

Comment: Of course, having transaction log backups taken every 5 minutes, instead of every hour, gives you more up-to-date backups.

Comment: @MaxVernon, I think you've answered the question by saying they're basically the same in terms of restore time. If you make your comment an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very small amount of overhead associated with reading headers from backup files.  The more backup files, the more overhead needed; however the amount of data actually read for each header is relatively small. The actual rollback/roll-forward work performed by SQL Server would be no different - SQL Server looks at the transactions in the restore file, and applies them to the database.

If your database has a lot of transactions per second, then each log backup will have a fair number of transactions within it, and the above logic applies.  If, however, you have a very low number of transactions over the 5 minute period, then the amount of data in any given 5-minute log backup would be quite small, and having lots of small log backups might increase the time needed for restore.

Having transaction log backups taken every 5 minutes, instead of every hour, gives you more up-to-date backups.  You could conceivably take that a bit too far, by say, doing a `BACKUP LOG` every 15 seconds.  This would create a huge number of backup files that would result in a myriad of other issues such as time required to read the file system structures for the folder containing the backups.  The key here is to use a bit of common sense, and balance the need for recent backups against the need to keep the number of files as small as you can.

Answer (score 0):

**Does it make a difference how many .trn files there are, if they cover the same transactions?**

You need to understand that while restoring a T-log, you cannot restore a T-log backup which is out of sequence.

for e.g If you took log backup every 5 mins for 1 hr then to bring the database up-to-date, you need to restore all the 12 T-log backups in sequence after fist restoring the full backup.
Keep in mind that all except last, restore should be done with norecovery. Last one would go with recovery.

As @maxVernon mentioned, taking frequent backups will help you bring the database more up-to-date and you have the flexibility of getting Point-in-time recovery in case of any disaster.

For fast or slow, obviously, a huge T-log will be slower to restore than a smaller one as it has to redo / undo all the operations that have happened since the last full backup to bring the database in a Consistent state.

Some excellent references can be found [here](http://www.karaszi.com/sqlserver/info_large_transaction_log_file.asp) and [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/73776/).

Comment: I don't know where the OP ever implied they would try to restore transaction logs out of sequence or skip any...

Comment: Right, I know I need to restore them in order. Here's the hypothetical I'm asking about: suppose the database needs to be restored and the last full backup was 2 days ago. Will it be a lot slower if I have 5-minute transaction backups (meaning there would be 576 of them) vs 1-hour transaction backups (meaning there would be 48 larger files)?

Comment: It depends on how many transactions have happened meaning if there are lots of Inserts/ Updates/ Deletes happened, then obviously it will take more time to rollback/rollforward during the restore phase.